# Arch Linux: Connman doesn't pick-up wifi internet connections

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux

So that's it. I can provide any info you need. I have installed the `connman`, `dmenu_connman-git` (AUR).

I am using OpenBox, along with the most recent version of Arch Linux (of course).

You can ask me to run any command and I'll update the question with the output. In the meanwhile, I can confirm that my wifi drivers are installed correctly, and I can receive internet in general (Ethernet).

If I run `connmanctl scan wifi` I get absolutely no output besides the "finished scanning" message.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nothing? I really need the wifi, I am currently in a very uncomfortable position to make the ethernet cable reach. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured it out. After many tests and research and not figuring it out, I figured it out.

I just had to install the `econnman` package from the AUR, run `econnman-bin -a` and voila! Selected my network, entered key-pass/password and it works.